# Appending data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi and thank you in advance for your comments. I have a database called CRIMDATA. Within that two tables called CRIM_PRODUCTION and another called ABBREV. Within CRIM_PRODUCTION there is a columns that has a string of data that contains various state abbreviations such as _fl and _ga respectively, for all 50 states embedded into a string such as images/broward_fl/12345.jpg in a column called IMAGES .

In the ABBREV table there is a column called SCORE that has all 50 states' abbreviations (_fl,_ga, etc) and a column for the postal abbreviation, and that column name is STATE, and has proper abbreviations like FL and GA for those abbreviations with the underscore.

What I'd like to do is generate a script that finds and matches on the occurrence of all the data in the CRIM_PRODUCTION IMAGES column, matched on the ABBREV SCORE column, and takes the data from the appropriate STATE column and copies it to the CRIM_PRODUCTION table and drops it into another column in CRIM_PRODUCTION table named SOURCESTATE.

Thank In advance everyone...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table name and columns name are not readable.

Check like this,

```
SELECT STATE
FROM CRIM_PRODUCTION P
INNER JOIN ABBREV A ON P.IMAGES LIKE '%' + A.SCORE + '%'
```

Then you can try like this,

```
MERGE CRIM_PRODUCTION AS TRG
USING (
    SELECT [STATE]
    FROM ABBREV
    ) AS SRC
    ON SRC.IMAGES LIKE '%' + TRG.SCORE + '%'
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET SOURCESTATE = SRC.[STATE];
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "P.IMAGES" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "A.SCORE" could not be bound.